# Position a view in relation to another view using RMQ

Tags: rubymotion, rmq

I begin today to use RMQ for my RubyMotion project.
I read the documentation of the frame / grid system but I cannot find a way to position a view related to another view.

I have 4 UIbuttons with an image inside. I want to place a UILabel under every button centered aligned.

I'm not using grid, i place my button with frame:

```
  def quiz_button(st)
    st.background_color = color.white
    st.frame = {l: 40, t: 160, w: 120, h: 120}
    st.image_normal = image.resource('sailboat')
    st.image_selected = image.resource('sailboat_selected')
  end
```

In MotionKit I have `"frame below(:username_input, down: 8)"`so I can place a view under a specific view, in RMQ I cannot find something that help me to do the same.

Comment: Don't forget RMQ's distribute!  It's very useful.  http://rubymotionquery.com/?s=distribute&post_type=document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in order (meaning the are siblings of each other and one after the other), you can use `below_prev: 8`, above_prev, right_of_prev, etc (bp:, ap:, rop: for abbreviations).

To get a specific view, you can use rmq in the normal way: `rmq(:username_input).frame.bottom)`. `.frame` returns a RubyMotionQuery::Rect instance which has tons of properties such as bottom and right.

So:

```
st.frame = {l: 40, bp: 8, w: 120, h: 120}
```

Or

```
st.frame = {l: 40, t: rmq(:username_input).frame.bottom + 8, w: 120, h: 120}
```